# removing black border from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My df:

```
Time       CPU
1:00:00    10
1:10:00    40
1:24:03    50
```

etc.

I am building a ggplot with this:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(Time, CPU)) + geom_line()
```

When I add the below code to the existing ggplot code, it puts a black border on the graph. Is there any way to remove that black border line around the plot?

```
p + opts(plot.background=theme_rec(fill="lightblue"),panel.background=theme_rect(fill='#D6E7EF')) + ylim(0,100) + opts(panel.grid.major = theme_line(size = 0.7, colour = 'white'), panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(), axis.ticks=theme_blank())
```

Comment: What version of ggplot are you using? (I ask because `opts` has been deprecated.)

Comment: Hi @joran, I am using ggplot2 version 0.9.0. Over all it works but I really dont like this black border.

Comment: Try setting `color` equal to something like `NA` or `"transparent"` for either/both of the `theme_rect`s for plot.background and panel.background. It's hard for me to help much more because that's such an old version. You really should upgrade.

Comment: @joran, I tried upgrading to ggplot2 version 0.9.3, it is giving me an error: Error in rename(x, .base_to_ggplot, warn_missing = FALSE) : 
  could not find function "revalue"
are you familiar witht this error?

Comment: Oh dear. Look, a _lot_ has changed between 0.9.0 and the current version. Much of your code will likely need to be changed.

Comment: @user1471980: install new version of plyr(install.packages("plyr")) to solve the "revalue" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do the following:

1. Update your R to the current 2.15.2 version.
2. Install the new versions of ggplot2, plyr, scales and gtable in a fresh R session with no other packages loaded apart from the standard autoloads.

This should more or less replicate what was in 0.9.0 using the new system. The plot I ended up with did not have a black border, so see if this works for you:

```
p <- ggplot(DF, aes(x, y)) + geom_line()
p + theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill="lightblue"),
         panel.background = element_rect(fill='#D6E7EF'),
         panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.7, colour = 'white'), 
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
         axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
    ylim(0, 5)
```

The primary changes are that opts() is now theme(), and theme_* is now element_*. In addition, a few new theme elements were added in order to support an inheritance structure of elements in the new system. For example, consider axis.text.y; this theme element inherits from axis.text, which in turn inherits from axis. There are a number of other changes, too, but unless you're writing theme functions, these are the primary ones that will arise in practice.